# MySQL get all unique values between two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

I have a table with two columns that contain ID's. I want to query the table to show one list of each ID from the two columns.

```
TABLE
A | B
-----
1 | 2
2 | 3
5 | 4
6 | 2
```

I want the result to be:

```
TABLE
  A
  -
  1
  2
  3
  5
  4
  6
```

Comment: You have a table with two COLUMNs you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the UNION operator

```
SELECT A FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT B FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Alternatively add them into a temporary table and SELECT them with ORDER BY (NOT sure if UNION will work if column A and B both have a similar value i.e "2"

Comment: +1. This is the most straightforward approach. @Achilles: The `UNION` set operator eliminates duplicate values; to disable that behavior, we'd use the `UNION ALL` set operator, which just concatenates the sets together, and doesn't do the extra step of going through the entire set to find and eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I agree with you. I guess it will be down to @Kevin to decide.

Comment: The resulting table does not contain duplicates in the question and the source columns does so duplication elimination is necessary (which UNION does, and UNION ALL does not).